# How can I select rows except last row of one column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to select one column only but all the rows except last row.

If I did it like below, the result is empty.

```
a = data_vaf.loc[:-1, 'Area']
```

Comment: `data_vaf.iloc[:-1]['Area']`

Comment: `df.iloc[:-1, index_of_col]`

Comment: You’ll need `iloc` for this task as you’re referencing the **position** of the row, rather than the row name/index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`loc`:location
`iloc`:index location.

They just can't operate implicitly.

Therefore we exclude last raw by `iloc` then select the column **Area**
As shown by the comment from *@ThePyGuy*

```
data_vaf.iloc[:-1]['Area']
```

---

Here's the structure of
`iloc[row, column]`

And
`iloc[row]` do the same thing as `iloc[row,:]`
`df.iloc[:-1]` do the same thing as `df[:-1]`

Comment: Thank you Baron. I understand the difference between loc and iloc. Since my row index are number. if I do data-vaf.loc[:-1] withou including column name, it would be fine. Why?

Comment: vaf.loc[:-1]  won't work if you don't have a row index called "-1", it's a nominal operation.

Comment: Since it's a nominal operation, it doesn't mean "last one". (it's all about what action you wanna make in nominal or numerical)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this as addressed in the comments using [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html).

```
df['col'].iloc[:-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Then we just `drop` the last row

```
out = data_vaf.drop(data_vaf.index[-1])['Area']
```